# LoadLibraryW fails with 122 ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER

Tags: c++, c, dll, loadlibrary

LoadLibrary has its limitation to use path of maximum ~260 chars. The LoadLibraryW should be able to load DLL from larger paths, but my test fails with error code 122 ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER, error message "The data area passed to a system call is too small."

LoadLibraryW fails for win32, but succeeds for win64 if path is longer than 260 chars.

Both win32, win64 LoadLibraryW works for paths shorter than 260 chars.

Can one explain the fail of LoadLibraryW on win32 long paths? Has other person encountered this problem?
How should I load win32 DLL from path longer than MAX_PATH ~= 260 chars?

My goal is to load win32 DLL from longer paths.

Code:
`LoadLibraryW(L"\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\adrian\\Desktop\\teste\\2352Debug\\testLoadW\\1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\\test.dll")`

Test conditions: windows 7, test.dll is a dummy DLL

Comment: Shouldn't the path string be prefixed with `L` to denote it as a unicode string?

Comment: Considering docs for `LoadLibrary` do not mention anything about UNC/long paths and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx) MS blog post mentions it as an example of function that fails with long paths, I think succeeding on x64  is the exception here, not the other way around. Maybe `SetDllDirectory` could be used as a workaround? Though I somehow doubt it.

Comment: Hmya, this is why it is such a mistake to use long path names and why Microsoft cannot offer a more solid solution.  It isn't like your code or the operating system doesn't support it, it is the code written by other programmers with a blind dependency on MAXPATH that is the problem.  LoadLibrary() is *not* an innocent call, way to much other code hanging off of it.  Hard to find too, including and not limited to your debugger and your anti-malware software.  The solution is trivial, you already know it.

Comment: @egur, thank you, my test included the `L`.

Comment: @user2802841, thank you for the link, it is the first I have seen that tell the LoadLibrary has problems with long paths. Also, I tried the `SetDllDirectory`, but no effect. I specify a full path, so the directory should not matter.

Comment: There's no way around it I think.. I tried `SetDllDirectory`, I tried  replacing half of the longest part with `...`, I tried `GetShortPathNameW`, `PathCompactPathEx`, etc.. None of them worked. That path name is even too long to send to the recycle bin.. It prompts you to "delete" the folder permanently even on an x64 system.. I don't get error 122.. I get error 126 on my system. Not sure that anyone can find a solution to this actually..

Comment: What about setting current dir to that directory, calling LoadLibrary and returning to the previous dir? If that fails, you should quit trying :)